# Unable to open file without it's full path in C++

Tags: c++, file, stl, fstream

I want to get file's content and print it in console, but the code bellow works only if I use full path and I don't want that, I am using Visual Studio 2022

```
int main() {

    std::ifstream file("folder/file.txt");
    std::string content = "";

    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (file) {
            std::string line;
            std::getline(file, line);
            content += '\n' + line + '\n';
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << content << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output: `Failed to open file`

but if I use full path like: `"C:\Users\User\...\folder\file.txt"` it will work.

Comment: it's likely the execution path is not where you think it is. (like `bin/` `debug/`)

Comment: Did you try creating a file at that path, just to find out where the relative path actually ponts to?

Comment: ***I am using Visual Studio 2022*** If you are running your program inside the ide the default working directory is set to `${ProjectDir}` which is a Visual Studio variable that contains the full path of the folder containing the project path. For relative paths your file should be relative to that folder. Although with that said if you click on your executable in the file explorer the default directory moves to the folder containing the executable which will be a different folder.

Comment: What does `std::filesystem::current_path()` return? Thats the current working directory relative paths are resolved against...

Comment: Paths can be specified as **relative** or **absolute**.  The relative path is relative to the *current working directory*.  In your case, the current working directory is not the one you presumed it was.  To help diagnose the situation, get the current working directory and print it out.  That should be enlightening.

Comment: OT: In `std::string content = "";` the `=""` part is not needed. `std::string content;` is all you need. The default constructor for std::string will properly initialize the string for you, no need to do that yourself. With this said this has nothing to do with the path problem.

Comment: You are using a relative path that is is (well) *relative* to the current working directory of your program when executing.  If you run the program in VS (e.g. within the debugger) then VS sets the working directory.  If your program is launched from a command line, the working directory is typically set by the command line interpreter (and affected by previous commands that change directory).  If running your program from a shortcut, one of the properties of the shortcut is the working directory. Your program can also get/set its own working directory (e.g. `std::file_system::current_path()`)

Comment: What directory do you want your relative path actually to be relative to? (If you see what I mean.)  Windows' 'current directory' is a fickle beast, I would not rely on it pointing anywhere in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the shorter comments give clues to the problem, but I'll provide a longer answer.

Many IDEs -- including Visual Studio -- do NOT have the current directory as your project area. Instead, the current directory when you run your program is in a build area.

Imagine your project is in C:\Users\You\MyProgram. You put the file there (or in a subdirectory), and when you run your program from the IDE, you expect to find it. And it's not there.

That's because the IDE actually sets the current directory to somewhere else. (I'm not sure where -- I don't use Visual Studio.) If you do this:

```
cout << std::file_system::current_path() << endl;
```

it should give you a clue.